# How to get audio (Mic) input working on Android with python/kivy

Tags: java, python, android, kivy, pyjnius

EDIT from a visitor:  The current consensus around this situation appears to be that Kivy does not support the microphone at this time, and we are begging people to help port the "audiostream" add-on forward, so that this can work again.  Any tiny work to help this is greatly appreciated.  More information below.

I try to get mic working on android, im using mainly kivy and buildozer
I got working audio out with audiostream, however that module is so outdated it wont work anymore if use input "recording" [GITHub Issue](https://github.com/kivy/audiostream/issues/25) .well i was unable to get recording working on pc because it says "unsupported" as soon i use record functions, on documents it mentions only mobile devices, so that is ok. it can be replaced on those platforms anyways with pyaudio.

I have tried to search other options what i can use, so i came up across pyjnius and MediaRecorder, im very novice with java,(and trying to learn python atm, so novice there too) so i was unable to get it working.
The problem lies, i need to get all mic data into bytes, this is easy with pyaudio, and it works. reason why im here, it is android where pyaudio not work(at least i havent yet tried compile libraries to android, i know this might be possible but alot work..)

Here is code what i have to try get it working:

```
            MediaRecorder = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder')
            AudioSource = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder$AudioSource')
            OutputFormat = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder$OutputFormat')
            AudioEncoder = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder$AudioEncoder')
            FileOutputStream = autoclass('java.io.FileOutputStream')
            gaindata = io.BytesIO()
    
            mRecorder = MediaRecorder()
            mRecorder.setAudioSource(AudioSource.MIC)
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)

            mRecorder.setOutputFile(gaindata.getBytes())
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)
            mRecorder.prepare()
```

I know there is something about FileDescriptor, there is some examples, but all them have spaces on strings so i have no idea how to convert them to python.. all i want is setOutputFile -> gaindata

If there is another option would be nice, i need bytesIO data from microphone(prefer 8000,mono,raw wav without header OR GSM6.10) and i will convert it with soundfile(yes i did compiled libsndfile.so to arm) into gsm6.10 and put it into socket, its a VoIP app.

Answer (score 0):

## audiostream

audiostream uses pyjnius as well

https://github.com/kivy/audiostream/blob/master/audiostream/platform/plat_android.pyx

```
from jnius import autoclass
    AudioIn = autoclass('org.audiostream.AudioIn')
```

I think best way would be fixing audiostream so other can use it as well because in the documentation of kivy it is mentioned to use it:

https://kivy.org/doc/master/api-kivy.core.audio.html

```
Note
The core audio library does not support recording audio. If you require this functionality, please refer to the audiostream extension.
```

Or you extract the core functionality of the project so you can use it.

## pyaudio

Other project I found using microphone is
https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/ which uses pyaudio

But I don't know if this works on android. Without your comment I would have thought it works because someone has created a kivy app to use it ...

https://github.com/jmercouris/speech_recognition

Comment: Thanks for answer.
audiostream, Well it errors out ImportError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "SDL_ANDROID_GetJNIEnv" dont know what to start fixing there..

pyaudio: well needs portaudio, and portaudio has no recipe. but i might able compile arm lib binaries to the android like i did on sndfile.so.
looking peech_recognition is nothing mentioned about android.. only kivy.

Comment: For fixing the `SDL_ANDROID_GetJNIEnv` bug I would try to migrate audiostream to SDL2 http://wiki.libsdl.org/MigrationGuide#Audio and if it works bingo

Comment: okey after looking more deeply, it will use SDL2 with recipe, also was able to compile it with only sdl2. so that is not issue. but i took a look into android_ext.h
there is 
`void audiostream_jni_register() {
        if ( !audiostream_jni_registered ) {
                JNIEnv *env = SDL_ANDROID_GetJNIEnv();
                jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "org/audiostream/AudioIn");
                (*env)->RegisterNatives(env, cls, methods, sizeof(methods) / sizeof(methods[0]));
                audiostream_jni_registered = 1;
        }
}
`
org/audi.. tried add android, there

Comment: it migh be  seems it cannot find the file AudioIn or something.. hmm

Comment: Modify your question so it's easier to help

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into it, you can still make recording audio works in PC using SpeechRecognition which uses PyAudio.
For mobile, I don't think Buildozer support that because I tried it and it didn't work.
audiostream seems to be outdated, but I haven't tried it yet.
edit:
i just tried using audiostream, but i can't seem to make it work.